# Replacing a Function with a Variable?

Tags: python, variables, call, function

I feel like this question is going to be silly, because I'm not entirely sure how to phrase it. I think it's best just to not over explain my question.

Okay, so on Code Academy they gave this assignment:

Below your existing code, define a function called `trip_cost` that takes two arguments, `city` and `days`.

Like the example above, have your function return the **sum** of calling the `rental_car_cost(days)`, `hotel_cost(days)`, and `plane_ride_cost(city)` functions.

Why/ How does the following work (I get it, but I don't get it.):

> It is completely valid to call the `hotel_cost(nights)` function with
>   the variable `days`. Just like the example above where we call
>   `double(n)` with the variable a, we pass the value of `days` to the
>   new function in the argument `nights`.

I did the code right and passed:

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475
def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        cost -= 50
    elif days >= 3:
        cost -= 20 
    return cost    
def trip_cost(city, days):
    return plane_ride_cost(city) + hotel_cost(days) + rental_car_cost(days)
```

At first I put `hotel_cost(nights)`, but then I changed it to `hotel_cost(days)` and passed. Now it strongly confused me. How & Why does the function grab from variables from the `def`? I guess I'm asking how does that work?

I'm trying to understand how to phrase the question. Can someone Break this down? Haha I don't even know what to title this because the concept is a bit confusing. I mean I get it, but I don't understand it (If that makes sense.) An does this **only** work when defining a function?

Also, why is it called "Calling a function", when in this case it's actually ***replacing*** a function?

Comment: The whole point of defining parameters is so that you can use them in your function. You should check out the [official tutorial on defining functions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a function e.g.: `def hotel_cost(nights)` the variable `nights` is *just a name* of whatever you pass into the function. It doesn't have to match the name of whatever you send in.

So when you're saying `def trip_cost(city, days):` Python is saying:
"Ok I'm expecting two variables in this function, one named `city` and one named `days`.

So when you try to call

```
def trip_cost(city, days):
    return plane_ride_cost(city) + hotel_cost(nights) + rental_car_cost(days)
```

Python says, "well I only know about `city` and `days`. There is no such thing as a `nights` variable to me and you'll get an error.

This is the case **even** if you call something like `cost = trip_cost(city, nights)`. While it is `nights` to the caller. As far as the function knows it only sees that second *thing* as `days` once it executes inside the function.

In a more technical definition, this is called **scope**. The scope of a function is what it can "see" outside of itself and what it cannot. In this case the only thing `trip_cost` can see is the two things given to it, the thing in position 1 which you defined as `city` and the thing in position 2 which you defined as `days`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking the codecademy course, and this topic confused me. But I learned that an `argument` is actually like the definition of the variable , and can be changed.so if you do:

```
def add(x):
    return x + 10
```

What the function does is inside the function, and indented. The argument, is like a *mathematical* `variable`. It represents another value, or `variable`. So that `argument` can be replaced by a variable, and every time that `variable` pops up in the `function`, it will be replaced by the substitute variable. There can be as many `arguments` as you want. A *functioning*(get it?) example is:

```
def math(x, y, z): # x is the operation
    if x == 'add':
        return y + x
    if x == 'subtract':
        return y - x
    if x == 'multiply':
        return y * x
    if x == 'divide':
        return x / y

mat = input('Enter an operation: ')
ma = input('Enter the first number:')
nat = input('Enter the second number:')

print math(mat, ma, nat) # This prints the function and everything returned to it, with the new arguments
```